# How to setup XBMC for BTSync?

Tags: kodi

I would very much like my Raspberry Pi with XBMC to run Bittorrent sync in the background.

I wish to use it to sync some photo albums on my phone with the device for the slide show. Want to use BTSync, since I whish to use multiple androids and have them all synced.

I stuck with getting the 'RPi-ip:8888/gui/' to work, so can't setup the USB drive to store the images.

Alternatively I could accept having 2 RPi, one that runs XBMC and another with runs some other Linux OS where BTSync is know to work. They just have to be able to share the same USB memory drive (planning to get a descent thumb drive to store it all - like 128 GB). Getting some help setting up such a setup would be appreciated and an acceptable answer/solution for me.

Comment: What distribution are you using, RaspBMC? How did you install Bittorrent sync and how did you try to setup the 'RPi-ip:8888/gui/'?

Comment: I use OpenELEC - it came with the kit (remote, IR sensor, preflashed SD-card) I bought. I don't mind changing dist, just want my remote to work.

Comment: I followed this tutorial (didn't setup the autostart) http://blog.bittorrent.com/2013/05/23/how-i-created-my-own-personal-cloud-using-bittorrent-sync-owncloud-and-raspberry-pi/ and another tutorial. Can't really remember which one the other was..

Comment: OpenELEC is not a debian based distribution like Raspbian, so there are a lot of things different. RaspBMC for example is based on Raspbian. I would suggest to use RaspBMC. With that, the tutorial should be easy to follow.